# Escaping elements in a URI Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, escaping, uri

I have a rails app that I am trying to do a get request with co-ordinates in...
I have a route in my routes.rb like this:

```
map.connect 'feeds/get/:location', :controller => "feeds", :action => "get"
```

I can send a string consisting of alphanumeric characters fine, but I need to send co-ordinates in a string in the URI as a get request:

```
51.896834,0.878906.
```

So, I escaped the string like so, and append it to my URI.

```
http://thisisnottheurl.net/feeds/get/51%2E896834%2C0%2E878906.xml
```

however it looks like rails automatically unescapes the string before the controller and gives me this routing error in the log:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/feeds/get/51.896834,0.878906.xml" with {:method=>:get}):
```

How do I stop rails escaping this string (with routes?) so that it can be read in the controller?

I looked at using the match function in routes.rb with regex, but that is rails 3 only...

Comment: Those need to be sent as parameters, not simply appended to the URI.  You can then retrieve them from your controller in the params hash (e.g. `params[:longitude]`).

Comment: Sorry, i am sending them as params with this route...
 `map.connect 'feeds/get/:location', :controller => "feeds", :action => "get"`

Comment: Can you please show the place where you are trying to send the coordinates?

Comment: `http://thisisnottheurl.net/feeds/get/51%2E896834%2C0%2E878906.xml`

Comment: Sticking them after the :id isn't the same as sending them as params.  You're probably looking for something like `get/51?lat=12.00023&long=52.02143`

Comment: ahh thank you, i need to just send them as params then!

Comment: I set them as params and it all worked fine.many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only real way I can think of doing this would be as follows, give the route a name as follows:

```
map.connect 'feeds/get', :controller => "feeds", :action => "get", as: 'get_feeds'
```

Then you would have a named route helper `get_feeds_path`, which you could then pass in location and a format as follows:

```
get_feeds_path(:location => '51.896834,0.878906', :format => 'xml')
```

What might be an even better idea however, is if you passed in two params, one for each of the coordinates.

```
get_feeds_path(:x_location => '51.896834', :y_location => '0.878906', :format => 'xml')
```

Then, the params hash passed to the controller should have a `params[:x_location]` and a `params[:y_location]` which you can manipulate to your liking.